# Android app hint "overlay animation"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn more about animation in android app development
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoeUAEHbZcQ << 1:26
I want to do something similar where if a button is pressed an animated hint will show. How can I do this. what topics should I look into

Comment: Try custom ShowCaseView Check this https://github.com/wooplr/Spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) which shows a example of how to define animations in XML, load them and execute on views. Also search for **ObjectAnimator** which lets you perform animations on the basis of view properties (eg. [alpha/transparency of view](https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/07/android-objectanimator-alpha.html)). GL!